# How do I insert blank entries for missing lines in an Excel spreadsheet (compared to a reference sheet)?

Tags: excel

All names below are randomly generated / fictitious.

I have the following Excel **Reference Sheet:**

```
Unit    Name                        Value
0001    Mandy D. Walker             6489
0002    Evelyn R. Paul              9487
0301    Brent A. Adams              7920
0302    Terry M. Odell              3707
0303    Michael L. Jones            2740
0401    Joyce K. Becker             91
0402    Rashad L. Wheeler           6667
0403    Faustino M. Aguilera        3755
0501    Richard S. Whittington      9413
0502    Bryce W. Wilder             121
0503    Barry C. Anders             36
0504    Calvin V. Unger             8101
0505    Tony E. Harris              9157
0506    Lloyd A. Walters            7173
0507    Rhonda G. Pagan             1584
```

Given the following  **Data Sheet:** with missing entries (Unit # 0303, 0402, 0503 etc)

```
Unit    Name                        Value
0001    Mandy D. Walker             7778
0002    Evelyn R. Paul              9776
0301    Brent A. Adams              6207
0302    Terry M. Odell              7144
0401    Joyce K. Becker             1696
0403    Faustino M. Aguilera        8065
0501    Richard S. Whittington      7958
0502    Bryce W. Wilder             6632
0505    Tony E. Harris              7216
0506    Lloyd A. Walters            4651
```

How do I create a sheet containing the values from the *Data Sheet* but with blank lines where the reference sheet has data but the data sheet does not?

**Desired Result:**

```
Unit    Name                        Value
0001    Mandy D. Walker             7778
0002    Evelyn R. Paul              9776
0301    Brent A. Adams              6207
0302    Terry M. Odell              7144
0303
0401    Joyce K. Becker             1696
0402
0403    Faustino M. Aguilera        8065
0501    Richard S. Whittington      7958
0502    Bryce W. Wilder             6632
0503
0504
0505    Tony E. Harris              7216
0506    Lloyd A. Walters            4651
0507
```

I need to do the above repeatedly, for many sheets, so I am thinking about a VBA macro (or very simple excel function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLOOKUP was made for this. Set the cells in column A in your new sheet equal to column A in the Reference sheet.

In cell B2 in the new sheet enter

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Data!$A$2:$A$11,Data!B$2:C$11,"")
```

Drag the formula down and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all 3 data is located in column A-C, with table1 in Sheet1, table2 in Sheet2 and table 3 in sheet3.. with the 1st data (0001) is located at cell A2..

in Sheet3 A2, put :

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

in Sheet3 B2, put :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

in Sheet3 C2, put :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

Then drag all 3 cells downwards. That should do.

Idea : get Unit from Sheet1(Table1), and other info from Sheet2. Blank if not found. useful ref : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Comment: Thanks, that works, though for my specific application, Axuary's answer using XLOOKUP is more elegant.

Comment: it's ok.. I cannot use the function in current excel version. Xlookup is a new function office 356 . Glad to know though. ( :